# I need my view controller to sit behind my tab bar

Tags: iphone, sdk, tabbar

I have a view controller, but when I hide the tab bar, there is just a black space where the tab bar was. I want to have my view controller sit behind the tab bar, so when I hide it, it shows the view content. I am using a simple UITabBarController. Thanks.

Comment: Did you resize your view in IB, specifically to accomodate the tab bar?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, as far as I'm aware. The problem is that the view controllers sit within the tab bar controller, not the other way around.

The way to get around this would be to change the window view for a new navigation controller without a tab bar controller, or use a modal view to show content without a tab bar controller.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your view on your view controller isn't tall enough to accommodate the space that your tab bar occupied.

```
CGRect current = [[self view] frame];
CGRect tabBarFrame = [[self tabBar] frame];

CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(current.origin.x, current.origin.y, current.size.width, current.size.height + tabBarFrame.size.height);

[[self view] setFrame:newFrame];
```

Something like that is probably what you want. Or you can resize it in IB.

But, I don't know why you would use a UITabBarController and then hide the tab bar... If you can't see the tab bar, you cant switch tabs... thus making the UITabBarController pretty much just a UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you give the view property of your UIViewController a fixed bottom margin and a flexible height then it will stretch to fill the height of containing view automatically.

```
mycontroller.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
```